# How to put symbol around the equal sign?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

In the question [Latex Math Symbol: Vitanyi puts a tiny plus symbol over his equals. How do I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273314/latex-math-symbol-vitanyi-puts-a-tiny-plus-symbol-over-his-equals-how-do-i-do-t), there was an answer to how to place additional sign over the equal sign.

And my question is, what if I also want to have some symbol/text under the equal sign?
Or if I want to use `\stackrel` to label my equal sign that follows an tab alignment character (`&=`)?

Comment: @user4217 --- I don't understand the second part of your question. Do you mean that you want to have text underneath an equals sign that follows an alignment tab character?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry I got it wrong in the question, I've edited it.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package provides the `\overset` and `\underset` macros that can be used to place one symbol above or below another. If you want text above and below, you could use `\DeclareMathOperator*` (also from `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\eq}{=}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\underset{b}{=} \quad  \eq^a_b
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

There shouldn't be any problems using this in `amsmath` environments such as `align`.

```
\begin{align*}
A  &\eq^b_a B \\
   &\eq^b_a C
\end{align*}
```

However, if you use it in the middle column of an `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*` (which are [generally considered to be obsolete](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)), then you will need `\displaystyle` before `\eq`.

All of the above applies to egreg's suggestion of defining `\eq` via

```
\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\mathrel{\operatorname*{=}_#1^#2}}
```

which seems to improve the spacing (and may be better in other ways as well).

Comment: In this case I would prefer `\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\mathrel{\operatorname*{=}_#1^#2}}}` to be called as `\eq{under}{over}`. In this way the symbol will behave like a relation symbol.

Comment: `\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\mathrel{\operatorname*{=}_#1^#2}}}` is not a balanced expression (one too many `}`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes --- well, that's what I get for copying from egreg's comment!

Comment: I suggest modifying egregs command to this form: `\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\mathrel{\operatorname*{=}_{#1}^{#2}}}` which allows empty strings as its arguments in case one wants text only above or below the operator